# Mudando valor de variável

Tags: r

Boa noite colegas:

Tenho uma variável numérica:

> cv1[1:10]  [1]      0      0 108919   4152    317 334403      0  35092
> 12762     NA

Quero criar a variável cv2, substituindo os valores absolutos de zero (0) por "NA". Usando a Função "gsub"ela substitui TODOS os numerais zero, inclusive nos números que têm zero no meio deles: (108919, 334403, 35092)

> cv2=gsub("0",NA,cv1)
>
> cv2[1:10]
> [1] NA      NA      NA      "4152"  "317"   NA      NA      NA      "12762"  NA

Como poderia fazer ma mudar somente os valores absolutos de zero para NA.Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um índice para saber em quais posições de `cv1` possuem `0`,

```
ind  <- which(cv1 == 0)
```

depois só substituir por `NA`:

```
cv2 <- cv1
cv2[ind] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é usar a função `is.na<-`.

Primeiro, ler os dados da pergunta.

```
cv1 <- scan(text = "0 0 108919 4152 317 334403 0 35092 12762 NA")
```

Agora, transformar os valores zero em `NA`.

```
cv2 <- cv1
is.na(cv2) <- cv2 == 0
cv2
#[1]     NA     NA 108919   4152    317 334403     NA  35092  12762     NA
```

Tal como na resposta do Rafael Cunha, modifiquei uma cópia do vetor `cv1`, mantendo o original.
Esta forma, com `is.na<-`, tem a vantagem de não criar um vetor extra, tal como o vetor `ind` na resposta do Rafael Cunha.